# Set value with dynamic attributes

Tags: jquery, dynamic, input, onclick

Why does this script not work? I want to put value of parent_id in input, please tell what do I have to do

```
    <script src="http://localhost/ci/social/assets/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".comment_link").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var element = $(this);
        var id = element.attr("post_id");
        var gi = element.attr("grand_id");
        var pi = element.attr("parent_id");
           $("#parent_id_"+id).val(id);
            return false;           
     });
    });
    </script>
    <a href="#" post_id="1" grand_id="0" parent_id="2" class="comment_link">Comment</a>
    <input type="text"  id="parent_id_2" value="" name="parent_id">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `post_id="1"` and `id="parent_id_2"`, can't you see the mismatch.

It should be

```
$("#parent_id_"+ pi).val(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#parent_id_"+id).val(id);
```

supposed to be

```
$("#parent_id_"+pi).val(id);
```

Value of **id= 1 ,  pi= 2**

But you do not have an element with id `$("#parent_id_1")`

You are looking for `<input type="text"  id="parent_id_2"`

[**Check Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kxc6s/)